# Replace a Fragment with a Layout containing a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

What I'm trying to do is have a master/detail style app where one of my selector options is a Google Map with some extra buttons below the map layout.

All my other options just load a Fragment into a FrameLayout, using something like:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content, myFragment, fragTag)
    .commit();
```

I can't do that with the MapFragment because I need other things in the layout and nested Fragments aren't supported (yet hopefully). So, I need to replace a regular Fragment with a composite view that contains a Fragment, but I'm not sure how the Fragment management should work here.

I don't think I can just call

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content, myCompositeView, fragTag)
    .commit();
```

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
Fragment currentFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content); 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(currentFrag);

LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.content);
container.removeAllViews();

View mapView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.store_finder, container, true);
```

It makes it a bit messy when replacing this with other fragments again as I need to remove all the views from the layout again. Also, I'm not sure how to properly remove the MapFragment after setting it up like this.

I'd appreciate any help and for someone to put my mind at rest :)

**Footnote**: Apparently Nested Fragments are a thing now, but not sure this is the way I want to go for something simple. http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

Comment: I used to use this trick: http://pastebin.com/CLRNd4BT how about it?

Comment: It just looks like you're replacing one fragment with another? That's not what I'm asking

Comment: *but not sure this is the way I want to go for something simple.* - there isn't another non messy way. A fragment was designed to be replaced by a another fragment and not with a layout + fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested Fragments are suppported, please see:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()

I'm using them in a current app / project and they work great. Not sure if there is any additional constraint with using them with your mapping view?

// WildStyle

Comment: Ye I just saw that they're supported and updated my question with a little footnote. I feel like this might be more messy than required. I'm finding dealing with MapFragments to be an abomination, because there's so much switching between UI thread and AsyncTasks and between stuff done in Fragments and stuff done in Activities. I don't want to make this any more complex than it already is :\

Comment: I can understand that .. however if you are wanting a complex composite view and would like to utilize the simplicity of replacing i.e. with another Fragment, then this would perhaps be the best way to go. Otherwise maybe you could have another content view / container in your main layout specifically just for the mapping, to use separately (show / hide when not not required)?

Comment: All I really need to add is a button and a TextView. Maybe nested Fragments is the best way to do this...